# "fatal error: No such file or directory" error in vscode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, arduino

I am in the midst of making an Arduino project in VSCode and I've decided to make some custom header files to make small, compatible libraries for some of the sensors I use.

After being done with writing, I placed them in my `Arduino/libraries` folder but when I tried using them in my project folder, I was handed the `main:1:10: fatal error: No such file or directory.` error. *The error is not specific as it gave the same error message even after I tried including each library individually.*

My `c_cpp_properties.json` file seems proper and I get no error lines under the `#include`'s in VSCode.

The only way I've came close to solving the issue was by writing the *whole file location* in the `#include` statement. *Which made me feel like there could be a cleaner way to do it.*

*I can also edit in my header files too, if necessary.*

Here is my main project file:

```
// Simplified file solely for testing as I couldn't get it to compile.
// The custom libraries I've mentioned.
#include <BTS7960B.h>
#include <MZ80.h>

MZ80 mz;
BTS7960B bts;

void setup(){
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
    // After I added the libraries this wouldn't even compile.
    Serial.println("Hello world.");
    delay(500);
}
```

Also the c_cpp_properties.json file:

```
{
    "version": 4,
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Arduino",
            "compilerPath": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\arduino-1.8.19\\hardware\\tools\\avr\\bin\\avr-g++",
            "compilerArgs": [
                "-std=gnu++11",
                "-fpermissive",
                "-fno-exceptions",
                "-ffunction-sections",
                "-fdata-sections",
                "-fno-threadsafe-statics",
                "-Wno-error=narrowing"
            ],
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64",
            "includePath": [
                "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\arduino-1.8.19\\hardware\\arduino\\avr\\cores\\arduino",
                "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\arduino-1.8.19\\hardware\\arduino\\avr\\variants\\mega",
                "c:\\program files (x86)\\arduino-1.8.19\\hardware\\tools\\avr\\lib\\gcc\\avr\\7.3.0\\include",
                "c:\\program files (x86)\\arduino-1.8.19\\hardware\\tools\\avr\\lib\\gcc\\avr\\7.3.0\\include-fixed",
                "c:\\program files (x86)\\arduino-1.8.19\\hardware\\tools\\avr\\avr\\include",
                "C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\Arduino\\libraries\\BTS7960B\\src",
                "C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\Arduino\\libraries\\MZ80\\src"
            ],
            "forcedInclude": [
                "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\arduino-1.8.19\\hardware\\arduino\\avr\\cores\\arduino\\Arduino.h"
            ],
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++11",
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using the Arduino plugin rather than manually configuring the compiler?

Comment: What about your tasks.json or are you using an extension?  c_cpp_properties.json sets the include path for Intellisense but not building and in the absence of a VSCode extension tasks.json handles the building.

Comment: @AlanBirtles if you're talking about the arduino library manager, I've used it and with time it caused more includePath issues and became unresponsive at times for unknown reasons hence i decided to abandon it and handle it manually.

Comment: @drescherjm I haven't tempered with tasks.json or any extension about tasks.json, i only use the arduino extension and the c++ extension